# reuse twig templates in symfony2 with inheritance

Tags: symfony, templates, twig

I have a symfony2 project which will be the base for a bundle of domains. Most configuration differences for those domains are done via the database. Like e.g. are the contents randomized, how many are shown on the start page etc.
But for some domains I want to use a different twig template for certain views depending on a categorization I do via the db.

Question 1: Is it possible to set it up like "if you find no template in place A use the default template from place B"? If yes how?

Question 2: Where would I place those templates in relation to the default templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1 : You can extend template with condition.

```
{% extends condition ? 'templateA' : 'templateB' %}
```

Question 2 : The best practice is to place the templates in views folder under the folder you want to create.

More info here : http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html

Comment: Thank you for the link. The paragraph "Overriding a Template that also extends itself" sounds very promising. I will check it out.

Comment: about your answer to Question2:

would the structure be for views beloning to the FooController
.../views/Foo/default
.../views/Foo/notdefault
or
.../views/default/Foo
.../views/notdefault/Foo

Comment: Yes ,  you can locate the templates where you want but best practice is under views folder as the documentation says http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations. Under views folder you can choose the hierarchy you want